# Regex how to match all end of line except blank line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

If I have text:

```
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC

DDDDDD
EEEEEE

FFFFFF
GGGGGG
HHHHHH
```

I want to match all end of line except the blank lines and replace the end of line to tab. `[^\s]$` partly works, but it also matches the last character of non-blank line. `[^^]$` does not work. What is the correct regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind regex:

```
/(?<!\s)$/mg
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oY0vU9/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookbehind for this purpose:

```
(?<=[^\s])$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD9cK8/1)

Comment: Happy to help.. although both are same i suggest you to use @anubhava's answer.. it gives better performance :)