# Regex to combine non-blank lines with tab character in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Apologies in advance.  My question has been asked before, and answered too ([Regex how to match all end of line except blank line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492293/regex-how-to-match-all-end-of-line-except-blank-line)).  I believe that the answer is not complete, with some obvious part (which unfortunately is not too obvious to me) left out.  Exactly like the OP, I want to combine all contiguous non blank lines with the tab character.

Input:

```
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC

DDDDDD
EEEEEE

FFFFFF
GGGGGG
HHHHHH
```

Expected output:

```
AAAAAA  BBBBBB  CCCCCC

DDDDDD  EEEEEE

FFFFFF  GGGGGG  HHHHHH
```

`/(?<!\s)$/mg` and `(?<=[^\s])$` have been suggested as the regex to use, but what should the replacement string be?

Comment: Please add the text and expected result to the question body.

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Comment: Sorry for that.  I ran into some formatting issues with my sample input and expected output.  I agree that I need to work more on posing the question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

**Find What**: `\S\h*\K\R(?!\R)`
**Replace With**: `\t`
**Regular expression**: *ON*

**Details**:

- `\S` - a non-whitespace char (detecting a non-empty line)
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces (maybe the line ends with some non-vertical whitespaces)
- `\K` - match reset operartor discarding the text matched so far
- `\R` -  a line break (CR, LF or CRLF)
- `(?!\R)` - not followed with another line break (avoid joining the empty line!).

See the screenshot with the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- `(\S)\R` as the **Find what** part and
- `\1\t` as the **Replace with**

of replacement dialog.

**Explanation:**

- the `\S` means NotWhitespace and `\R` means lineending
- the parens store the last non whitespace character before a linenend into `\1`
- the replacement use this and `\t` which is the tab character to get rid of the undesired linebreak

Comment: Your approach will result in empty lines being joined with the last matched non-empty one, and will fail to join non-empty lines that end with horizontal whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.